# Concrete Mathematics - The Josephus Problem

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

I've been going through [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) and have a question on the inductive proof for the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Recurrent relation:

> $J(1) = 1$
>
> $J(2n) = 2J(n) - 1$
>
> $J(2n+1) = 2J(n) + 1$

Closed form hypothesis:

> $J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1$, for $m \ge 0$ and $0\le l<2^m$

Inductive Proof (for the even case):

> $J(1)=1$
>
> $J(2^m+l)= 2J(2^{m-1}+l/2)-1=2(2l/2+1)-1=2l+1$

How do the authors get from $2J(2^{m-1}+l/2)-1$ to $2(2l/2+1)-1$?

Comment: Because of the hypothesis

Comment: @Yimin I understand that it comes from the hypothesis, but not how $2l/2+1$ can be plugged in for $J(2^{m-1} + l/2)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1$ is your hypothesis. You prove it for $n=0$ and $l=0$. Now comes the step. You assume the hypothesis for numbers smaller then m and l.

Then for $n=m-1$ and $k=\frac l2$, you have $J(2^n + k) = 2k + 1=\frac{2l} 2+1$ from the hypothesis. This is induction.

Comment: In the last part, did you mean $2k + 1=\frac{2l} 2+1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you introducing $k$ here? And how does this proof the hypothesis?

Comment: And why is $n = m - 1$? The book states $2n = 2^m + l$, so I guess you could write that as $n = (2^m)/2 + (l/2)$, but that is all I can do.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. I had to work through the previous parts of the chapter again to understand why equation (1.8) in the book holds. What helped me was drawing out all the steps.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of our induction, we assume that our hypothesis is true. A reminder of our hypothesis:

$J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1$

If that's true then:

$J(2^{m-1} + l/2) = 2l/2 + 1$

And if that's true then:

$2J(2^{m-1} + l/2) - 1 = 2(2l/2 + 1) - 1$

Which is, of course:

$2l + 1$

The even part of our induction is complete.

Comment: Very clear explanation - as I understand it then - we are massaging our hypothesis into a form that we can plug into the even recurrence RHS thereby "tipping the dominos" completing our induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Base case.**
Obviously $J(1) = 1$.
**Inductive step.**
Assume $J(\frac{n}{2}) = J(2^{m-1} + \frac{l}{2}) = 2 \cdot \frac{l}{2} + 1.$
We have $J(n) = J(2 \cdot \frac{n}{2}) = J(2^m + l) \stackrel{(1.8)}{=} 2J(\frac{n}{2}) - 1 = 2l + 1.$
Proofed.